# windows phone 8.1 Toggle switch off color always transperent

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

Am using toggle switch of windows phone 8.1 (Don't want to use WPToolKit)

Am able to change the toggle switch color, when IsOn=true (ToggleSwitchCurtainBackgroundThemeBrush). **But when the toggle switch is off, it is taking default background color.
Is there any property to change the Toggle switch color when IsOn=false ?**

Thanks,
Snober

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could play with the **RequestedTheme** (Dark/ Light) or as a better option, change the style/ template.. **Open in Blend** > **Right click on the item (ToggleSwitch)** > **Edit Template** > **Current** .. then you can play with the template as you want :)

You can refer to this post for more: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30199.make-a-styled-button-in-xaml-for-universal-windows-apps.aspx

*(This post about Button control, but you can do it for any control)*

Comment: Thanks. Got it from blend. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to modify the Template of your ToggleSwitch ?
You should be able to modify the background of the toggle switch by adding a background color to the element "OuterBorder".